# RSpec controller testing: missing template on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have an interesting situation. I am testing the following simple create action:

```
# will only be accessed via Ajax 
def create
 click = Click.new(params[:click])
 click.save # don't really care whether its success or failure
end
```

Then I have the following very simple controller spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ClicksController, "creating a click" do
  it "should create a click for event" do
    xhr :post, :create, :click => {:event_id => 1}
    # more test to come...
  end
end
```

Seems trivial, yet I get the following:

**Missing template clicks/create**

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add to the controller action:

```
render :nothing => true
```

This one will automatically create the appropriate server's respone. More [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-nothing)

Answer (score 5):

You will get this error if your controller renders only JSON or XML, yet you don't specify a format in the spec; your request then defaults to unsupported HTML. In that case, simply specify the supported format when you invoke the controller method from your spec. For example, change this:

```
post :create, registration: @user_hash
```

to this:

```
post :create, registration: @user_hash, format: :json
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not render anything in a controller action, rails will attempt to default to rendering a template (in this case `clicks/create`). I'd suggest rendering back at least a success message like so:

`render :json => {:success => true}`

Answer (score 1):

Building on [megas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999488/rspec-controller-testing-missing-template-on-create/11999571#11999571), if you're looking to test a controller action that's only accessed via a UJS link and only has a .js.erb template, I'd put this in the controller to avoid breaking your UJS functionality:

```
respond_to do |f|
  f.html { render nothing: true } # prevents rendering a nonexistent template file
  f.js # still renders the JavaScript template
end
```

This will enable you to call the controller action by simply calling [`ActionController::TestCase::Behavior`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html)'s `get`/`post`/`put`/`delete` methods instead of needing to call `xhr`, because it will successfully call the method, render nothing, and continue on, while leaving your UJS behavior intact.